# ¿Arrays y objetos son lo mismo?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

¿Cómo es que `materias[materia][0]` es una variable?

Al parecer sí se comporta así y no sé porqué, puesto que lo inicializé como *OBJETO*.

Alguien que me ayude a entender cómo dentro del `for` se puede usar así.

Estoy intentando solucionar e imprimir en consola una lista en este orden: [ asistencia, promedio, trabajos entregados, nombre de la materia ], añadiendo color a los que aprobaron para diferenciar.

```js
const materias = {
    fisica: [90,6,3,`fisica`],
    matematica: [80,5,4,`matematica`],
    logica: [95,9,3,`logica`],
    quimica: [89,8,4,`quimica`],
    calculo: [87,6,3,`calculo`],
    programacion: [88,7,4,`programacion`],
    biologia: [91,8,2,`biologia`],
    algebra: [79,8,1,`algebra`]
}
//Los Array asociativos son objetos...
const asistencia = () => {
    for(materia in materias){
        let asistencias = materias[materia][0];
        if(asistencias >= 90){
            console.log(`%c${materias[materia][3]}`, 'color: #444; font-size: 15px');
            console.log('   %cAprobado', 'color:green');
        } else{
            console.log(`%c${materias[materia][3]}`, 'color: #444; font-size: 15px');
            console.log('   %cDesaprobado', 'color:red');
        }
    }
}
asistencia();
```

Comment: No, [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) y [Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) no son lo mismo. El hecho de que puedas acceder a las propiedades de un objeto con la notación de corchete no significa que un Objeto sea igual a un Array. Por otro lado, no existen *Arrays asociativos* en Javascript. Saludos

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Estás planteando varias preguntas. En particular, el título de la pregunta no coincide con el contenido de la pregunta, en la que planteas el funcionamiento particular de un código.

Comment: A lo que te ha comentado @MauricioContreras he de agregar que lo que parecen ser matrices asociativas en realidad son propiedades de la clase accedidas a través de la notación de corchetes (`objeto["propiedad"]`) en vez de la notación de puntos (`objeto.propiedad`). Puedes consultar más acerca de este asunto en el siguiente enlace: [Acceso a las propiedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dicen otros compañeros, un Array y un Objeto no son lo mismo, tienen diferentes métodos y trabajamos con ellos de forma diferente.

Tu confusión parece estar en el uso de los corchetes para acceder a las propiedades de los objectos. Los corchetes son una alternativa a la notación con punto.

Imagina este objeto

```
const myObj = {
  myName: "My name!",
  "my name": "Also my name"
}
```

La primera propiedad se podría acceder utilizando ambas notaciones `myObj.myName` o `myObj["myName"]`.

Sin embargo, la segunda propiedad, al tener un espacio (lo cual es una mala práctica), sólo podría accederse utilizando la notación de corchetes `myObj["my name"]`, puesto que `myObj.my name`, daría error puesto que intentaría acceder a la propiedad `my` de `myObj` y name sería una variable sin iniciar.

Ahora tu caso concreto:

Dentro del for, cuando utilizas `materias[materia]` estás utilizando la notación de corchetes de la siguiente manera:

1. `materia` es una variable que inicias al comenzar el loop `for(materia in materias){` (que, de hecho, bien escrito, sería algo así como `for(const materia in materias){` si no mutas la propiedad o `for(let materia in materias){` si la mutas) y que hará referencia a la `key` o referencia de la materia que toque en ese momento.
2. Al utilizar la notación de corchetes que expliqué antes, esa variable se "resulve" (materia --> "fisica"), quedando algo así `materia["fisica"]`, accediendo al valor de esa propiedad, quedando un array y por tanto accediendo a él con corchetes y el índice deseado. `materias[materia][0]` sería lo mismo que `materias["fisica"][0]` en última instancia.

Espero que haya quedado claro, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Una matriz no es lo mismo que un objeto, pero una matriz es un objeto. En particular, una matriz es una instancia de la clase [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```js
const a = { uno: 1, dos: 2 };
const b = [ 1, 2 ];

/* a es un objeto */
console.log("Tipo de 'a':", typeof a);
/* b también es un objeto */
console.log("Tipo de 'b':", typeof b);
/* a no es una instancia de Array */
console.log("¿'a' es una matriz?", a instanceof Array);
/* b sí */
console.log("¿'b' es una matriz?", b instanceof Array);
```

Que coincida la manera en la que se puede acceder a un elemento mediante la notación de corchetes y la de punto es solo debido a que los ["property accessors"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) (traducido en algunas partes como "accesores de las propiedades") son iguales para ambos.

En las matrices se crean de manera automática las propiedades numéricas necesarias para almacenar los elementos, a las que no es posible acceder mediante la notación por puntos:

```js
const a = { 0: 1, 1: 2 };
const b = [ 1, 2 ];

/* Accediendo a las propiedades numéricas de a */
console.log("a[0]:", a[0]);
console.log("a[1]:", a["1"]);
/* Accediendo a las propiedades numéricas de b */
console.log("b[0]:", b["0"]);
console.log("b[1]:", b[1]);
/* En ambos casos son propiedades: */
console.log("¿'a' tiene a propiedad '0'?", a.hasOwnProperty(0));
console.log("¿'b' tiene a propiedad '0'?", b.hasOwnProperty("0"));
console.log("¿'a' tiene a propiedad '2'?", a.hasOwnProperty("2"));
console.log("¿'b' tiene a propiedad '2'?", b.hasOwnProperty(2));
```

Las propiedades en los objetos son realmente cadenas de caracteres, por lo que podremos acceder a las propiedades usando de manera indistinta números o cadenas de caracteres que contengan el número.

Por lo tanto lo que realmente diferencia `a` de `b` es que `b`, al ser una instancia de `Array`, tiene muchos métodos para trabajar con sus elementos (como [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) o [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) y, a su vez, actualiza el valor de ciertas propiedades de manera dinámica (como la propiedad [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)).

---

Comento cual es el funcionamiento de tu código:

```js
const materias = {
  fisica: [ 90, 6, 3, `fisica` ],
  matematica: [ 80, 5, 4, `matematica` ],
  logica: [ 95, 9, 3, `logica` ],
  quimica: [ 89, 8, 4, `quimica` ],
  calculo: [ 87, 6, 3, `calculo` ],
  programacion: [ 88, 7, 4, `programacion` ],
  biologia: [ 91, 8, 2, `biologia` ],
  algebra: [ 79, 8, 1, `algebra` ],
}

/* Es buena idea proporcionar como parámetro los datos */
const asistencia = materias => {
  /* El bucle "for .. in" itera las propiedades de un objeto */
  for (materia in materias) {
    /* Aquí dentro el contenido de "materia" será el nombre de cada propiedad */
    /* El primer elemento de la matriz que hay en cada propiedad se considera la asistencia */
    const asistencias = materias[materia][0];
    /* El tercer elemento coincide con el nombre de la propiedad */
    console.log(
      `%c${materias[materia][3]}`,
      'color: #444; font-size: 15px'
    );
    if (asistencias > 90) {
      console.log('   %cAprobado', 'color:green');
    } else{
      console.log('   %cDesaprobado', 'color:red');
    }
  }
}

/* Ejecutamos la función pasando como parámetro "materias" */
asistencia(materias);
```

> **¿Cómo es que materias[materia][0] es una variable?**
>
> Al parecer sí se comporta así y no sé porqué, puesto que lo inicializé como OBJETO.

La variable `materia` contiene el nombre las propiedades en cada iteración del bucle `for .. in`, por lo que `materias[materia]` contiene una matriz de cuatro elementos, así que al usar `materias[materia][0]` estás accediendo al primer elemento de dicha matriz.

Has "definido como objeto" la variable `materias`, pero el contenido de cada propiedad es una matriz que, a su vez, contiene cuatro elementos de diferentes tipos (enteros o cadena de caracteres).

Answer (score 0):

> > En Javascript, los tipos de
> > datos definidos son : (booleano, número, cadena, null, undefine) y
> > objeto los arrays son un tipo de objetos. con caracteristicas
> > diferenciales y propias
> > Si Un Array  dispone de constructor

```
const array = new Array(1, 2, 3);
```

> Dispone de metodos nativos:
>
> push(v) ;pop();shift();push(v) y muchos mas conocidos Arrays  son
> un tipo de objetos y sus elementos son propiedades con nombres 0, 1, ..
> .  dispone de metodos especiales para manejar sus propiedades por
> ejemplo length
>
> Podemos  detectar a un array

```
// typeof materias:--> object  typeof materias[materia] object 
// Array.isArray(materias[materia])  true
    //con-->Array.isArray(value)
    const materias = {
        fisica: [90,6,3,`fisica`],
        matematica: [80,5,4,`matematica`],
        logica: [95,9,3,`logica`],
        quimica: [89,8,4,`quimica`],
        calculo: [87,6,3,`calculo`],
        programacion: [88,7,4,`programacion`],
        biologia: [91,8,2,`biologia`],
        algebra: [79,8,1,`algebra`]
    }
    
    const b = typeof materias;
    console.log('materias:',b)// materias: object
    
    
    
    const asistencia = () => {
        for(materia in materias){
            console.log('materia',materia)
            // fisica,matematica,logica,quimica//,calculo,programacion
            let asistencias = materias[materia][0];
            console.log('typeof materias[materia]',typeof materias[materia])
             console.log('Array.isArray(materias[materia]) ',Array.isArray(materias[materia]))
            console.log('asistencias',typeof asistencias,asistencias)// number
            
        }
        }
    /*
    materias: object
    materia fisica
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 90
    materia matematica
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 80
    materia logica
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 95
    materia quimica
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 89
    materia calculo
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 87
    materia programacion
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 88
    materia biologia
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 91
    materia algebra
    typeof materias[materia] object
    asistencias number 79
    
    
    */
    asistencia();
```